# Ramanujan formula and atomic orbitals

Tags: sequences-and-series, quantum-mechanics

[image] This formula from Ramanujan contains the sequence of the number of electrons for a subshell s,p,d,f,g,...Is a coincidence or is there a deep reason why such a formula could arise in quantum mechanics?

Comment: You mean, the arithmetic progression $2$, $6$, $10$, $14,\ldots$?

Comment: Yes! It is likely an accident, but I remembered that recently some pi formulae were rediscovered in the framework of quantum formalism...So, I wondered if this formula could also be explained or reappear in the quantum context for atomic orbitals or any other problem. Of course, I am aware it could be a completely naive observation...

Comment: Like this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07813

Comment: Usually a chemist who sees the arithmetic progression $2,6,10,14,...$ will think of _molecular_ orbitals in conjugated rings, not atomic orbitals.

Comment: I strongly doubt it has any relation. In the formula of number of electrons in a shell $2(2\ell+1)$, the $2$ factor come spin degree of freedom while the $2\ell+1$ part comes from rotational degree of freedom. The spin part is  an internal degree of freedom and more or less arbitrary (i.e. there doesn't seem to be any real reason that it has to be $2$). It is hard to see it can fit into any scenario that can/will generate a number according to Ramanujan's formula.

Comment: And this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01214 I knew I had seen something...Of course, I can just only smell something in all this. And it could be only an anecdote

Comment: nice paper @riemannium